# Get ID and Quantity of list of products in an array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, arraylist

I have some foreach loop who get some list of products, each product have his `id` and `qty` field.

So i want to get in some variable all the id and quantities something like:

```
$var = array(3) {
  [0] => array(2) {  //product1
    ["id"] => int(1) "2"
    ["qty"] => int(2) "50"
  }
  [1] => array(2) {  //product2
    ["id"] => int(1) "6"
    ["qty"] => int(2) "30"
  }
  [2] => array(2) {  //product3
    ["id"] => int(1) "9"
    ["qty"] => int(2) "99"
  }
}
```

**My products:**

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $prod) : ?>
    <?php if($prod->isSaleable()): ?>
        <?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($prod) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $prod->getId()?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php if(!$prod->isGrouped()): ?>
                <?php $productId = $prod->getId(); ?>
                <?php $productCartQty = $this->getCartQty($prod); ?>
                <div class="border-new-cart-button">
                    <span class="plus qty-add" style="float:right;" onclick="plusQty('qty-<?php echo $productId ?>')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-qty-product number-control" title="Qty" value="<?php echo /*$this->getProductDefaultQty() * */ 0 ?>" name="qty" id="qty-<?php echo $productId ?>"/>
                    <span class="moins qty-remove" style="float:right;" onclick="minusQty('qty-<?php echo $productId ?>')"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <button type="button" class="btn add-to-cart" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Valider') ?></span></button>
            <input type="hidden" name="products[]" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
         </form>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In a Front it looks like:

```
<form action="http://domaine.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3Bmc2ZvLnByb2pldHMtcHJlcHJvZC5jb20vaG9tbWUvdmV0ZW1lbnRzL3Qtc2hpcnRzL3Qtc2hpcnQtb3ZlcnNpemUuaHRtbA,,/product/1641/form_key/wtBQE1VnebqTbkym/" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_1641">
    <div class="border-new-cart-button">
        <span class="plus qty-add" style="float:right;" onclick="plusQty('qty-1641')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
        <input class="input-qty-product number-control" title="Qty" value="0" name="qty" id="qty-1641" type="text">
        <span class="moins qty-remove" style="float:right;" onclick="minusQty('qty-1641')"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span>
    </div>                                           
    <button type="button" class="btn add-to-cart" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span>Validate</span></button>
    <input name="products[]" value="1639" type="hidden">
</form>
```

Comment: is this a javascript question?

Comment: Yes, it seems possible to do it in JS, the important thing is to get my data in some variable